# How to pass variable through promise chain using finally

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, promise

I am trying to build a log for an `Express API`, however am having issues getting the data to log out.

I can log the original `req` and `res` objects in the `finally` block, but am not sure how I would access the `SQL response`.

```
const sql = require("mssql")
const config = require("../config")

router.get("/express-route", (req, res) => {
  sql.connect(config.properties).then(pool => {
    return pool.request()
      .input('username', sql.NVarChar(32), req.params.username)
      .execute('do_something_with_username')
      .then(response => res.send(response) // pass this response
      .catch(err => res.send(err))
      .finally(() => {
        console.log('response', response)  // to here
        sql.close()
      })
  })
}
```

How would I take the response from the first `then` block and pass it to the `finally` block to be used in another function?

Comment: You can't - if there was an error in `request` or `input` or `execute`, the `finally` callback runs but there never was a `response` value. So what are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: @Bergi Trying to capture data like the request body, request headers, response body, etc. to write to a log in SQL.

Comment: You should write that log when you are sending the response, not after you handled an error. You certainly will need to capture different data to your log in case there was an error. `finally` is not the right place to do that

Comment: Is there another verb I can use other than `then` to help break up the visual flow during the scope of the log?

Comment: "then" is generally classed as an adverb, not verb :-)

Comment: @Matthew Not sure what you mean by "visual flow". You have to decide on the control flow that you want, and then use the methods that are available to achieve it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> A finally callback will not receive any argument, since there's no reliable means of determining if the promise was fulfilled or rejected. This use case is for precisely when you do not care about the rejection reason, or the fulfillment value, and so there's no need to provide it. ([mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/finally#Description))

Instead, simply use `.then`:

```
const sql = require("mssql")
const config = require("../config")

router.get("/express-route", (req, res) => {
  sql.connect(config.properties).then(pool => {
    return pool.request()
      .input('username', sql.NVarChar(32), req.params.username)
      .execute('do_something_with_username')
      .then(response => {res.send(response); return response;}) // pass this response
      .catch(err => res.send(err))
      .then(response => {
        console.log('response', response)  // to here
        sql.close()
      })
  })
}
```

Comment: Awesome. Thank you!!

Comment: Don't forget that `response` will be `undefined` if there was an error, since that's what the `catch` handler returns.

Answer (score 0):

You can, in fact, simplify things by writing your code within an async function

```
const sql = require("mssql")
const config = require("../config")

router.get("/express-route", (req, res) => {
  sql.connect(config.properties).then(async pool => {
    try {
        const response = await pool.request()
                         .input('username', sql.NVarChar(32), req.params.username)
                         .execute('do_something_with_username');

        // do another request
        const otherResponse = await pool.request() ... ;

        res.send(response);
    } catch (err) {
        res.send(err);
    } finally {
        sql.close();
    }
  })
}
```

This lets you write code in a more linear manner.

Comment: The idea is to replace ` console.log('response', response)` with another `pool.request...` to write back to SQL...

Comment: And you can do that, just call like I did with the first pool.request in my answer

Comment: Thank you for the feedback!! :)